# How to debug unclean socket closure in C?

Tags: c, sockets, unix, network-programming

I have a network daemon (poll()/accept()/fork() style) which is leaking socket file descriptors, one per client in the TIME_WAIT state.

As far as I can see I can shutdown()ing and then close()ing definitely-no-longer-needed sockets. Other sockets (for example the server socket in the client side of the fork) are just close()ed. All sockets have SO_REUSEADDR set and SO_LINGER is off. I am using _exit() to exit the program and I am using non-blocking polling socket operations so as to set a ''dying'' flag in my signal handler -- this allows me to later pick up the dying flag and free(), shutdown(), close(), which would otherwise be dangerous in a signal handler.

But still a fd leak -- What is the best way to debug this kind of problem? It would help to know which socket is loitering at exit, as there are many fds involved in the process.

Cheers!

Comment: Some code would be useful to see.

Comment: I don't have a minimal example to hand - if no-one has any ideas, i can post a tarball of the entire codebase.

Comment: What OS are you using? Different OSes have quite different tools for debugging this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sockets in TIME_WAIT mode are NOT leaking -- TIME_WAIT means that the application has finished with the socket and has closed it and cleaned it up, but the kernel is still remembering the socket so as to respond properly to late/orphan/duplicate packets that might be floating around in the network.  After a little while, the kernel will automatically delete the TIME_WAIT sockets, but until then, they remain as a reminder to the kernel to not reuse the port unless an app specifically asks for it with SO_REUSEADDR.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out.

Infact I had fixed the bug already by closing the cli_fd in the server side of the fork; however I did not notice the bug was fixed because i was using natstat wrongly to could open fds.

For the record, the output of `netstat -n | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l` should not be used to count file descriptors for sockets which are hanging around -- this is what i was doing wrong. Use lsof or fstat instead.

Anyway - the server is no longer running out of fds under considerable load.

Cheers